# how to play rtsp streamming in QT

Tags: c++, qt, streaming, rtsp

I am trying to find a way to play in [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) 4.6 rtsp streaming, that i got from youtube api
can it be done somehow?

Comment: This would be a good place to use correct capitalization on Qt, which is not QuickTime. (QuickTime 4.6 is a non-existent version number, but if it did exist, it would have supported RTSP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live555](http://live555.com/) has some very useful libraries on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [**Phonon**](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/phonon-overview.html), multimedia framework for QT.

Comment: it doesn't support rstp . i guess i need to combine few stuff to make it work ,but i have no idea what

Comment: RTSP support depends on the backend being used.  The Symbian backend, for example, supports playback of RTSP streams by passing the `rtsp://` URL to `MediaSource::MediaSource(const QUrl&)`

Comment: i need it for windows XP at first and then in mac
what about JRTPLIB can i use it? with QT ? if yes how the two can be integrated ?

Comment: can someone show me example how to use it with rtsp with back end ?

Answer (score 1):

The most seamless way is to use Phonon.

If you are using Windows, Phonon uses DirectShow as the backend.  To utilize this you need a RTSP DirectShow source filter, which you register in Windows.  There are commercially available ones and a few open source projects that may have what you need.

For example,
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtspdirectshow

A good rule of thumb is if you can play it in Windows Media Player (mplayer2.exe, wmplayer.exe), you can play it using Phonon.  Currently you would not be able to play a URL containing "rtsp://" in WMP or Phonon is because no DirectShow source filters are installed which support RTSP.

Comment: and what about integrate Gstreamer and QT in win?
is it recommended ?

Comment: Phonon uses GStreamer in Linux only I believe.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html#backends
The backends of Qt use the media systems DirectShow (which requires DirectX) on Windows, QuickTime on Mac, and GStreamer on Linux.

Comment: can you explain me how applications for example http://www.muziic.com/
stream from youtube ?